# Quamash and PyQt5 - extra window appearing at the end of process

Tags: python, asynchronous, pyqt5

Good day, I am currently learning asynchronous processes using Quamash and PyQt. I am trying to convert the example in https://github.com/harvimt/quamash as a class. I seem to be doing something wrong since there's an extra window appearing at the end of the process. I hope someone can guide me to the right direction.

Thank you!

Also using Python 3.4, PyQt5.

```
import sys
import asyncio
import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QProgressBar, QMessageBox
from quamash import QEventLoop, QThreadExecutor


class QuamashTrial(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(QuamashTrial, self).__init__()

        self.initialize_widgets()
        loop.run_until_complete(self.master())
        QMessageBox.information(self, " ", 'It is done.')

    def initialize_widgets(self):
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.progress = QProgressBar()
        self.progress.setRange(0, 99)
        self.progress.show()

        self.setLayout(vbox)

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def master(self):
        yield from self.first_50()
        with QThreadExecutor(1) as exec:
            yield from loop.run_in_executor(exec, self.last_50)

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def first_50(self):
        for i in range(50):
            self.progress.setValue(i)
            yield from asyncio.sleep(.05)

    def last_50(self):
        for i in range(50,100):
            loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.progress.setValue, i)
            time.sleep(.05)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    loop = QEventLoop(app)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    with loop:
        q = QuamashTrial()
        q.show()
        loop.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you call `show()` function twice - in `__main__` function and `initialize_widgets()` function. So this is why you see extra window.
Secondly, if you use `loop.run_until_complete(self.master())` you don't need to call `loop.run_forever()` because the loop stops after `self.master()` completion.

I think your **main** function shoud be like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    loop = QEventLoop(app)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    with loop:
        q = QuamashTrial()
```